# Can we getLastknown location or approximate location without using GPS On in android?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-gps

I am writing an services which suggest near by facilities
I am using fuseAPI and asking for last known location so that i can suggest at least something. If I am asking user to on GPS he is uninstalling app.

I have used standard code of google to get last known location I thought it will give last known location even if user off GPS.

Answer (score 0):

Google API let you choose location provider, GPS or Network (Access Point, if supported).
The way to do this it using `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`

In additional, You can check if the provider is enabled (if your AP support location) with `isProvideEnabled` method:

```
boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```